# Excel - transposing certain cells in a row of data

Tags: microsoft-excel, transpose

I have an excel spreadsheet, similar to below, with sets of two rows which are identical (other than column 3 and 4). Some rows do not have an identical consecutive row (in this case row 3). For each set, I would like to transpose column 3 such that it looks like the second spreadsheet that I have copied in.

Y   X   2   FALSE
Y   X   1   TRUE

C   D   5   TRUE

E   F   6   FALSE
E   F   7   TRUE

i.e I would like to combine the two identical rows, whilst transposing column three in order to keep the two different numbers. For single rows, the TRUE/FALSE in column 4 should indicate which column it should be transposed into. It should look similar to this:
Y   X   2   1

C   D       5

E   F   6   7
I do not have a lot of experience with excel but any help would be appreciated. 
I have hundreds of rows of data like this, so cannot do this manually.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it would be like this:

Add a column after the original third column, where you want the information from the second row in a pair to appear. If your example data is in `A1:D5`, this would be a new column `D`.

Then, we're going to fill it with the information from the row below only when the flag in the next column is set to `FALSE`. In `D1`, use the formula `=IF(NOT(E1), C2, "")`. You can now copy or drag this formula across the entire column and the rows with `FALSE` should contain exactly what you want.

We're going to be removing rows and the references in our formula will break, so copy the entire column `D` and paste it in place **as values** (via *paste special...* from the right-click menu).

Now we can remove the unnecessary rows. Select everything and use **Filter** (**Data** tab, **Sort & Filter** group). Use the dropdown in column `D` to only display blank values, then select all rows which remain visible and delete them.

Finally, disable **Filter** to again reveal the rows which by now should contain the data in the desired form.